# Constructing matrices that are diagonalizable or not

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What are some methods where I can construct a matrix that is diagonalizable or not quickly for some constraints such as it being singular or not or it having complex eigenvalues for 2x2 and 3x3 matrix. So far what i have done to check is to find the eigenvalues and use that to find the number of eigenvectors to see if they equal n columns of the matrix, but this is time consuming.

Comment: You can construct a diagonizable matrix by using a diagonal matrix and multiplying it with by rotation matrices on both sides.

Comment: Have you learnt about [Jordan forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)? To get a non-diagonal matrix, you could just take a non-diagonal Jordan block or Jordan matrix, for example. And you can easily select the eigenvalues of such a matrix (they are just the diagonal elements of it), so you can easily make it singular (by giving it a $0$ on the diagonal) or have a complex eigenvalue (if you're happy to have complex entries).

Comment: no its not taught in this class, but i did hear a little about them , but i don't full understand it

Comment: Then how did you learn about diagonalization?

Comment: Well for $2\times 2$ case, taking a matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda\end{bmatrix}$ (for some scalar $\lambda$) will give you a **non-diagonalisable** matrix eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: does it also work with distinct eigenvalues

Answer (score 0):

If you want to construct an $n\times n$ matrix $A_\lambda$ with a single eigenvalue $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ which is *not* diagonalizable then use a Jordan block:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 1 &  &   \\&\lambda&1&\\&&\lambda&1\\&&&\ddots\end{pmatrix}.$$

The Jordan block is not diagonalizable since if it was, $A - \lambda I$ would be too. But $A - \lambda I$ is an upper triangular matrix with zeros on the diagonal, which implies it has one eigenvalue: zero. But if $A - \lambda I = P D P^{-1}$ where $D$ is the zero matrix, this implies $A = \lambda I$, a contradiction. Thus we can conclude that $A$ is not diagonalizable.

If you'd like $A$ to be diagonalizable, just use a diagonal matrix:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda&&&\\&\lambda&&\\&&\lambda&\\&&&\ddots\end{pmatrix}.$$